# How do I disable a specific band on my Android phone (Sony Xperia Ion)

Tags: dialer-codes

I'm interested in purchasing an Asus Padfone X or S for use on T-mobile.  However, it doesn't support band 1700, which means that I will only get 4g in areas with refarmed 1900 spectrum.  T-mobile helpfully tells me "Pittsburgh has been refarmed", which doesn't tell me if my home 15 miles south of the city will work on that.

I currently have a Sony Xperia Ion that I'm using.  I would like to use this phone to test the 1900 coverage.  How do I disable the 1700 band on my phone to see what sort of 4g coverage I get?  I tried *#2263#, which I found at http://forums.androidcentral.com/t-galaxy-s-iii/201259-how-disable-lte-t-s3-you-can-disable-hspa-too.html, but my phone just says it's an invalid phone.

Comment: I vaguely remember there was some `build.prop` tweak, but I'm not 100% sure. Trying a google search on "build.prop 4g 1900 1700 frequency" at least turned up 1900 = Band 2, 1700 = Band 4. Using that as input for another Google search: `"build.prop" 4g disable "band 4"` gives you several good entry points to try at least (3,000 hits). Most solutions however might require root (certainly will when you must edit `build.prop`). Luckily, there are several "dialer codes" mentioned along. Good luck!

Comment: @Izzy I'll try doing some research with this as a starting point.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Anytime! Please remember to [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) when you've come up with results :) Good luck!

Comment: @Izzy I'll certainly do that if I can.  If this requires rooting the phone, though, I may not try it.  This was an AT&T phone that I had to go through all kinds of craziness with to get to work on T-Mobile.  I don't want to risk locking myself back out.

Comment: I found http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2469536, which I feel may have gotten me half way there with dialer code *#*#4636#*#*.  However, I don't know which of the options, if any, disable the 1700/2100 bands.  I'll post again if I learn any more.

Comment: AFAIR, that code is for usage stats (apps, battery, etc.). Long time not checked, maybe things have changed … But again I vaguely remember having seen some "band options" in one of those "secret menus". Keep my fingers crossed!